# Can't make jar anymore in Netbeans after new jre, jdk update

Tags: java, netbeans, compatibility

I' am really angry. Last summer I started to create a game in java, after one month I had more than 5000 lines of working code. Perfectly working, 0 errors or malfunctions. Tested the jar file on every OS. Used JDK 7.

I delayed the job, and after three months I brought my game to my friend to show him, and it's doesn't work anymore.

Runned inside new Netbeans 8 totally good working,  but  can't make Jar anymore, because long list of errors.

I found this disastreous. After every jre update you need rewrite your code? Then I will never do any java programs again, going back to C. Eclipse is better?

I don't want to share my code.

What can I do to make my program again runnable with a jar file without rewrite my code? I tried to install older JRE' but this doesn't help the situation.

Thank you! Sorry for my English.

Added part program errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:  1
        at kj01.kezdolap.jButton6ActionPerformed(kezdolap.java:1006)
        at kj01.kezdolap.access$2100(kezdolap.java:32)
        at kj01.kezdolap$19.actionPerformed(kezdolap.java:801)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You should be able to compile using java 7 if you look at the compiler switches javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 .....  Java has a policy of supporting 2 versions behind so java 1.7 will still be possible with jdk 1.9

Comment: And post your errors. They will help someone to identify the exact line (or lines) which might have caused the errors.

Comment: *I don't want to share my code*: then we can't find the bug uour code has. Don't blame Java for your own bugs. And if you don't want to share your code, then you'll have to find the bug by yourself (which shouldn't be hard, BTW). Voting to close: questions asking for debugging help must include the relevant code.

Comment: You don't understand what is my problem. Read, I said I had a working code. After 3 months it's no longer works. If you write a code in java, just like in C that works, why doesn't work after a time?  And why my code works perfectly inside Netbeans? In last summer my jar file worked also. I can fix problems, but the question is that you need fix your good program after a time? Isn't java backward compatible? Somebody said in another forum that I lied about the flawlessly working program. I don't like debugging help just a general answer. Do you need to rewrite programs?

Comment: Did I violate java standards? Maybe Netbeans jumped my errors?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the answer.

Netbeans jumps out Arrayoutofbounds type errors but the jre compiler doesn't. Somehow older jre compiler jumped out the Arrayoutofbounds errors. So Netbeans can run the app with Arrayoutofbounds error.

I ported my app to Eclipse that right away warned me:

```
.splits() caused the problems.
```

Edit:
I did split file location inside source directory and outside of source it cannot found the file locations.